# ASP.net suggestions as you type

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have an asp.net website with some tables (Radgrids) connected to a MSSQL. The users enter data in few tables and then they assemble other tables using drop down lists with the values entered earlier.

I am experiencing some double entry in few data tables and I am considering to implement a `suggestion as they type` to show similar entries already existing in that column of the database. Something like **SO Questions that may already have your answer**.  A sort of popup showing entries already saved in that column with similar words.

A reference to something similar or to a type of controls used for these kind features will be appreciated. Not being a professional in coding I am looking for a starting point.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe something like jQuery UI Autocomplete?  http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: @David Thanks for referencing a starting point. :-)

Comment: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/autocompletebox/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: If you just want to stop users adding the same entry into the database, this should be handled in the DB or in the validation.  You're effectively saying if the `Auto Complete` shows nothing, then they can add?

Comment: @christiandev, yes I wont to stop users to add same entries. The problem I am facing is a little bit more complex because most of those entries are like "Donald Duck" already existing and a user add again "Duck Donald". Having to deal with company names and projects names I cannot reduce the entry to a single word.

Comment: You could add a `unique constraint` on the DB column? Are you saying if the table has Donald Duck, then Duck Donald should be rejected?

Comment: @christiandev, yes that would be already a good result. The best would be to show the user a list of similar entries already in the database.

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy, thanks but the example does not work on radgrids. I already inquired them.

Comment: as suggested above, use the Jquery Autocomplete, http://techbrij.com/jquery-ui-autocomplete-asp-net-web-api.  This will do what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [AjaxControlToolKit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx)

It has a decent (if not good) Auto Complete extender control that can be used to display values from a database.

Simply download the .dll and add it to your websites bin folder and you should be good to go.

You simply create a quick Page Method or web service that has a method which matches the required signature :

```
public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count) { ... }
```

and you can return an array of the matched values of "Prefix Text", to do this you will need to use either [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090.aspx) code or some other way of finding the matched values.

You can also customize the look of the dropdown box and the number of items to display in the box should you wish.